# How can I open async several selenium webdriver using python

Tags: python, selenium, pool, ui-testing

Please help! I want to open several webdrivers and for each do different actions, for example for first opened webdriver do login, for second registration etc. I try to use Pool library, but it doesn't work correctly, it opens webdrivers not paraller.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

class C:
    def log(self,  url):
        print("1")
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/path")
        driver.get(url)

    def reg(self, url):
        print("2")
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/path")
        driver.get(url)


    def f(self, *name):
        return name

    def run(self):
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        pool.map(self.f, (self.log("someurl?form=sign_in"), self.reg("someurl?form=sign_up")))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = C()
    c.run()
```

Comment: personally, I think the word `async` is misused in your title, as it may induce to think you refer to asynchronous python programming. I think `parallel` works better

Comment: Question 1: what do you want method `f` to do?

Comment: Question 2: methods `log` and `reg` do no return anything, are you sure they behave as you want them to? i.e. right now the pool workers are being fed `None`

Comment: Question 3: are you sure you really need to use Selenium and cannot use other means to hit the site/API?

Comment: Question 4: why don't you instantiate the driver once only, i.e. as `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/path")` within the `__init__` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Selenium Grid 4](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/grid/grid_4/) is what you're looking for.